# Using https for the GAE application in "Google Apps"

Tags: security, google-app-engine, https, google-apps, application-settings

I would like to use https for my GAE Application through "Google Apps" (Such a confusing terms: "Google App Engine" and "Google Apps") for security.

My GAE Apps is accessed via https (e.g. https://mygaeapp.appspot.com). When this GAE Apps is accessed via "Google Apps", it is accessed through http (e.g. http://myapp.mydomain.com). I would like it to be https (e.g. https://myapp.mydomain.com) for security reason. If you look at the screenshot, there is no option for https. (I have already enabled SSL in my "Google Apps" via "Domain Settings"->"General"->"SSL".)

Should I have concern for that or I am secured because my GAE app is accessed vi https anyway (i.e. https://mygaeapp.appspot.com). Any links to documentations or setting will be appreciated.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Google App Engine doesn't support](http://code.google.com/p/googleappengine/issues/detail?id=792&colspec=ID%20Type%20Component%20Status%20Stars%20Summary%20Language%20Priority%20Owner%20Log) (yet) SSL for custom domains, only thru the appspot.com domain (i.e. https://my-app-id.appspot.com).

Comment: ok, thx Shay. The feature has been in request since 2008! I have added my vote.

Comment: @user319058 is but its in started mode now

Comment: you mean, it is in "testing" (or beta) mode ? It won't be long before the feature is available then. That's a good news.

Answer (score 1):

It is officially on the roadmap and soon to come : http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/roadmap.html